# call to nested function in javascript using object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this javascript function called wire_quick_search in a file1.js

```
function wire_quick_search()
{
    console.log('hits wire_quick_search');
    empty_count=0;
    var load_search_result=function(payload,id,class_name,max_empty_count){
        console.log('hits load_search_result');
    };
}
```

Now I am trying to access the load_search_result() from a php method but for some reason I keep getting undefined function. Here is the sample code from the php method.

```
private static function _return_order_search_only($text,$count_flag=1)
    {
        $html="
        <div class='level_1_container'>
            ".self::_render_order_search_container()."
        </div>
        ";
        $js="
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var key='key=".self::get_key()."';
            payload=key+'&event=".self::ACTION_GLOBAL_ORDER_SEARCH."&text=$text';
            var obj1=new wire_quick_search();
            obj1.load_search_result(payload,'order_search_id','order_search_class',$count_flag);
        });
        ";
        return array($html,$js);
    }
```

Here is the screen shot of my console.
[image: console log]

so how do I access the load_search_result function?

Comment: you're dumping text from PHP directly into a JS context. are you **SURE** that nothing could ever be output from your php code that'd be a JS metacharacter, e.g. a `'`?

Comment: All the metacharacter are sanitized by a master class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused by the example, maybe I am just reading it out of context but from what I can see your internal function `load_search_result` is a private function.

When you create the new instance of your object you cannot access it in the manner you are trying without using `this` in your original object to make it public.

```
function wire_quick_search() {
    console.log('hits wire_quick_search');
    empty_count=0;
    this.load_search_result=function(payload,id,class_name,max_empty_count){
        console.log('hits load_search_result');
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, that really helped. I had been trying to figure that out for past 3 hours :)

Comment: Good answers regarding the use of they keyword 'this'. I added some comments that illustrate some important considerations when doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function wire_quick_search()
{
    console.log('hits wire_quick_search');
    empty_count=0;
    this.load_search_result=function(payload,id,class_name,max_empty_count){
        console.log('hits load_search_result');
    };
}
```

Note the `this.load_search_result` instead of `var`.

A variable defined with `var` by definition must not be visible outside the block it is designed in. With `this` you add a public visible object member.

Answer (score -1):

Important caveat!

Regarding the use of the keyword 'this' in the examples above. That happens to work, because the context of 'this' *at the time of invocation* happened to be a global invocation context. Howerver, there is an important caveat that you might want to be aware of going forward:

Consider:

(And before you test this, be sure you refresh your browser, otherwise load_search_result will still remain in memory in the global context and my example will seem meaningless).

```
function wire_quick_search() {
    console.log('hits wire_quick_search');
    empty_count=0;
    this.load_search_result=function(payload,id,class_name,max_empty_count){
        console.log('hits load_search_result');
    };
}

var notGlobal = {
    wire_quick_search: wire_quick_search
};

notGlobal.wire_quick_search(); // => 'hits wire_quick_search'
load_search_result(); // => ReferenceError: load_search_result is not defined
```

The reason `load_search_result` is undefined in the global context is due to the fact that *at the time of invocation*, the keyword 'this' referred to notGlobal, and remains bound to that.

To further illustrate my point:

```
notGlobal // => { wire_quick_search: [Function: wire_quick_search], load_search_result: [Function] }
notGlobal.load_search_result() // hits load_search_result
load_search_result(); // => ReferenceError: load_search_result is not defined
```